# How to join the results of two XPath expressions using the concat function?

Tags: xpath

I have following XML:

```
<root>
    <chp id='1'>
        <sent id='1'>hello</sent>
        <sent id='2'>world</sent>
    </chp>
    <chp id='2'>
        <sent id='1'>the</sent>
        <sent id='2'>best</sent>
        <sent id='3'>world</sent>
    </chp>
</root>
```

Using the XPath expression

```
root/chp/sent[contains(.,'world')]/@id
```

I have the result `2 3` (which is exactly what I want), but when I run

```
concat('sentence ', /root/chp/sent[contains(.,'world')]/@id, ' - chap  '  ,  /root/chp/sent[contains(.,'world')]/../@id )
```

the result breaks at the first result:

```
sentence 2 - chap  1
```

Comment: I think you should be using XSLT to produce the output you require. Try `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="//sent[ contains(.,'world')]">
chap <xsl:value-of select="../@id"/> sent <xsl:value-of select="./@id"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
`  Sorry - formatting is not great in a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last argument does not contain a single value, but a sequence. You cannot use XPath 1.0 to join this sequence to a single string. If you're able to use XPath 2.0, use `string-join($sequence, $divisor)`:

```
concat(
  'sentence ',
  string-join(/root/chp/sent[contains(.,'world')]/@id, ' '),
  ' - chap  ',
  string-join(/root/chp/sent[contains(.,'world')]/../@id, ' ')
)
```

which will return

```
sentence 2 3 - chap  1 2
```

Most probably you want to loop over the result set yourself (also requires XPath 2.0):

```
for $sentence in /root/chp/sent[contains(.,'world')]
return concat('sentence ', $sentence/@id, ' - chap ', $sentence/../@id)
```

which will return

```
sentence 2 - chap 1
sentence 3 - chap 2
```

---

If you **cannot use XPath 2.0**, but are able to further process results in some outside programming language (like Java, PHP, ...) using DOM: Use `/root/chp/sent[contains(.,'world')]` to find the sentence nodes, loop over them, then query the `@id` and parent (chapter) `@id` using DOM and construct the result.